# Is it possible to allow non-admin users to manage Email Alert recipients?

Tags: administration, security, email-alert, delegated-admin

My client would like certain users to have the ability to manage Email Alert recipients. Right now their org is to setup to send to specific users, but if we had to, we are willing to setup Public Groups if there's a way to delegate administration of those. According to [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h06UAAQ), this is not possible, though.

Is there any way to give specific users (groups or profiles) the ability to manage who receives email alerts without granting admin profile?

Thank you.